# Unexpected line occurs when making wavy shape with SVG:

Tags: html, svg

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K6V7.png)

This line occurs and disappears as I change the viewport width.

I tried to make a curvy background by adding `<svg>` on top of the actual `<div>` with same color as background.
I have tried many suggestions found on google and youtube, such as reducing `viewBox="0 0 1440 155"` last number by one. Also tried `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` on `svg`. None of these helped.

Please see the attached image.

The problem is on

```
<div class="footer__wave">
```

Here is the HTML :

```html
<footer class="footer">
      <div class="footer__wave">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 155" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path
            d="M0 99.424C249.852-14.173 492.347-30.427 727.484 50.661c352.706 121.632 501.421 140.534 727.484 0 150.71-93.69 150.71 129.423 0 669.339H0V99.424z"
            fill="#00252E" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper footer-grid">
        <div class="footer__col-1">
          <img class="footer__logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
          <span class="footer__text"
            >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse,
            voluptatem voluptates itaque odit id necessitatibus.</span
          >
          <div class="footer__contact">
            <img src="./images/icon-phone.svg" alt="phone" />
            <span class="footer__text">Phone: +1-543-123-4567</span>
          </div>
          <div class="footer__contact">
            <img src="./images/icon-email.svg" alt="email" />
            <span class="footer__text">example@huddle.com</span>
          </div>
          <div class="footer__social">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-twitter"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__col-2">
          <span class="footer__text-uppercase">Newsletter</span>
          <span class="footer__text"
            >To recieve tips on how to grow your community, sing up to our
            weekly newsletter. We'll never send you spam or pass on your email
            address. <br />
            ( unless we do )
          </span>
          <form class="footer__input">
            <input type="email" />
            <button>Subscribe</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
The same is true for `<input>`

Comment: Can you put your full page html, with eventually css? I tried to reproduce, I don't have line!

Comment: Please try adding `display:block` for the svg element

Comment: unfortunately `display:block` on `svg` didn't help.
Here is the repo: https://github.com/mark-pherz/HTML-CSS-junior-5
Here is deployment: https://mark-pherz.github.io/HTML-CSS-junior-5/

You have to play with window width to see the line

Answer (score 0):

You can start off reducing the problem by placing the SVG as a background in CSS and pacing a bit off to the left and top, so that you don't end up in a situation where one pixel-width can be either white or blue. And then you can also reduce the problem by making the wave white and cover the top part of the footer. In this example the SVG is repeated on x, so that the issue don't show to the right (and the wave always have the same height).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #00252E;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDE1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0gMCAwIFYgMTAgQyAyMCA1IDMwIDUgNTAgMTAgQyA3MCAxNSA4MCAxNSAxMDAgMTAgViAwIFoiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: 500px;
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  padding: 75px 1em 1em 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  Above
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper footer-grid">
    <div class="footer__col-1">
      <img class="footer__logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      <span class="footer__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse,
            voluptatem voluptates itaque odit id necessitatibus.</span>
          <div class="footer__contact">
            <img src="./images/icon-phone.svg" alt="phone" />
            <span class="footer__text">Phone: +1-543-123-4567</span>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__contact">
      <img src="./images/icon-email.svg" alt="email" />
      <span class="footer__text">example@huddle.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__social">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-twitter"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer__col-2">
    <span class="footer__text-uppercase">Newsletter</span>
    <span class="footer__text">To recieve tips on how to grow your community, sing up to our
            weekly newsletter. We'll never send you spam or pass on your email
            address. <br />
            ( unless we do )
          </span>
    <form class="footer__input">
      <input type="email" />
      <button>Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```